# Multiple list levels in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm about to lose it. After some research, it seems you can only have nested bullet points (list levels) if you are using the default "paragraph" text element.  I have a bunch of custom slides in which list levels do not work. What's really weird is if I copy and paste the list, it pastes with all the list levels I (tried to) insert.

I really need nested lists inside a table, for instance. I refuse to believe there is no way to do this.

Without creating a NEW presentation, how can I get nested bullet points in a table in powerpoint?

edit: I have determined this is something with the existing document causing list levels to not work at all. I can open a new blank document and everything works as expected. Is there some document setting that would cause this?

Comment: You can sort of force things, for instance by ending one link by pressing ENTER, then using the Increase Indent Level button (Home tab, Paragraph group) to indent it. If you apply a bullet style to this line, any new lines you add will keep the same bullet style, but if you add a new line and decrease the indent level, you'll need to reset the bullet style to whatever's appropriate for that indent level.  IOW, you can force it but it's clumsy as all getout.

Comment: In an attempt to show you that this does not work, I discovered it DOES work, just not in the document I've been working in.  Something in this one document is causing list levels to not function. In a blank document list levels work in text boxes, tables, everything else I tried.  What on earth would cause them to NOT work?

Comment: I created a new blank slide in the presentation in question and bullet list levels do not work in any scenario. This must be a document wide setting somewhere. Please send help.

Comment: If it's something specific to one presentation that causes a normal PPT feature not to work, it's hard to guess what the problem might be w/o seeing the file in question. Can you post it (or a cut-down version with no sensitive information) online someplace where it can be downloaded?  Also, please indicate whether you use Mac or Windows, and what version of PowerPoint  you have.